# implementing drag and resize on the same element

Tags: jquery, html, css, resize, drag

I am trying ti implement resize and drag on the same element. Check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lo8n75dg/

my code so far:

```
   $('#dragbar').mousedown(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
          //$('#position').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
          $('#sidebar').css("width",e.pageX+2-100);
          $('#main').css("left",e.pageX+2);
       });
    });

   $(document).mouseup(function(e){
       $(document).unbind('mousemove');
   });

      $('#sidebar').mousedown(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
          //$('#position').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
          $('#sidebar').css("margin-left",e.pageX-100-$('#sidebar').offset().left);
          //$('#main').css("left",e.pageX+2);
       });
    });
```

The idea is that if mouse down happened on the black line, the code preforms resize. If mouse down is on red rectangle, the code make horizontal drag.

This 2 event currently conflict, that is why you see flickering. Any idea how do I fix that?

UPDATE:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lo8n75dg/2/
I added e.stopPropagation() which does part of the trick. There is unfortunately still a lot of flickering going on for reasons unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

Below seems to work for me in the fiddle. Please use this in both the places.

$('#sidebar').css("position","absolute");
$('#sidebar').css("left",);

Let me know how it works out for you :)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent mousemove conflict you can store which block is currently being dragged.

```
const resizebar = {
  node: wrap.querySelector('.resizebar'),
  isDragged: false,
}
const dragbar = {
  node: document.querySelector('.dragbar'),
  width: 200,
  x: 0,
  isDragged: false,
}
```

Also I think that flickering in your code is caused by calculation of `margin-left`

I tried making pretty much same block in native js -
 https://jsfiddle.net/Ellaylone/48h5L8t1/